# Uploaded Image file not being saved to the directory( flask python)

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

So, I am trying to save this user uploaded image file into my directory using flask. Everything works fine except the image is not getting saved.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for,render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            print("File is saved successfully in the uploads folder!!")
            # return redirect(url_for('upload_file',
            #                         filename=filename))
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<h1>Uploads</h1>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">

</form>
```

There are no errors. Please help me know what's wrong.

(P.S: Please ignore the open secret key, I will secure it later :'))

Comment: Can you paste your html code too?

Comment: Your code looks ok. Have you tried setting UPLOAD_FOLDER as a full path? 
Upload your html code too, maybe there is a problem with the form that handles the file

Comment: @IoaTzimas please check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change input name as below (If it doesn't work try with action="/")

```
<h1>Uploads</h1>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="upload">
```